# Signed difference between two directions

Tags: orientation

I want to get the difference between the orientation of my robot and a target point. The orientation is expressed as an angle as shown in the pictue below. The point is expressed as `(x, z)` in a cartesian space that has origin in the robot position. The x and z axis are always fixed.

This image explains how the angle and the axis are intended.

[image]

I need the angle between the orientation and the target, and I need it to be positive/negative when the target is left/right.

Comment: ok, you described what you need ... however, you did not ask any questions ... i can think of two different questions off the top of my head ... what question is yours?

Comment: I have answered a similar question here, I think it might help.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22133/how-to-detect-if-object-is-moving-in-clockwise-or-counterclockwise-direction/183892#183892

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the [heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heading_(navigation)) of your own vehicle, you then need to find the [absolute bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_bearing) of your target so you can find the [relative bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_bearing) between your vehicle and the target.

The best way to do this, if you have the x/z position of the target, is with the [atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), where:

> `atan2(y, x)` returns a single value θ such that −π < θ ≤ π

If you just use `atan` then you wind up with an ambiguous result and you need to check/offset the answer by checking the signs of y and x. The `atan2` function does this automatically.

Comment: It might be good to add that the two angles can just be subtracted and the result normalized.